# google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I need to fetch data from google cloud datastore using python, when fetching all the collection it succeed, but when try to fetch specific value according to the key it failed, I provide the store data method and fetch data method:

```
def store_data(name, value):
    entity = datastore.Entity(key=datastore_client.key('visit', name))
    entity.update({
        'name': name,
        'value': value
    })
    datastore_client.put(entity)

def fetch_name(name):
    query = datastore_client.query(kind='visit')
    print("name is: " + name)
    # query.add_filter("name", "=", name)
    results = list(query.fetch())
    # print("GET - param is results: " + results)
    return jsonify(results)
```

which mean, if I uncommit the line:

```
 # query.add_filter("name", "=", name)
```

will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 107, in getVariable
    times = fetch_times(name)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 40, in fetch_times
    results = list(query.fetch())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 208, in _items_iter
    for page in self._page_iter(increment=False):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/page_iterator.py", line 244, in _page_iter
    page = self._next_page()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/query.py", line 610, in _next_page
    response_pb = self.client._datastore_api.run_query(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore_v1/services/datastore/client.py", line 579, in run_query
    response = rpc(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found.
```

and the response return: Internal server error. How can fix that ?

I tried to add indexing from the UI of google cloud page - add index to name property.

Comment: You'll want to check the mode of your database (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases/describe).  It's likely your database is in Firestore native mode instead of Firestore in Datastore mode.  If so, you'll want to use the Firestore client libraries instead of the Datastore client libraries.

Comment: Thanks @JimMorrison I use firestore client libraries, but when deploying the app to google cloud, I get **502 Bad Gateway - nginx**
Errors: line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>, in <module>
    import firebase_admin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'

Comment: Looks like your second attempt is using some Firebase library.  You may want to check out https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library .

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check the mode of your database (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases/describe). It's likely your database is in Firestore native mode instead of Firestore in Datastore mode. If so, you'll want to use the Firestore client libraries instead of the Datastore client libraries, or switch your database type to Datastore mode.